# Aggregating Getstream notification feed

Tags: node.js, notifications, aggregation, getstream-io

Please I would like to know how to properly display the response data from getstream notification. I'm using a node server.

By this I mean that Getstream just gives "raw" data back details the activities in a particular group. How can I then display the notification based on the response to something like "John and 3 other people followed you".

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your application and your taste. You have all necessary information in the response. You might want to check the docs and examples: https://getstream.io/react-activity-feed/tutorial/

Comment: I am using nodejs with flutter and flutter doesn't have any clients in that regard.

Comment: Yes, we don't have feed examples for flutter but I guess react examples should give enough inspiration.

Comment: Yeah, I found a post of someone who made something similar using typescript. I was able to understand it and I now know what I need to do.

Comment: Great, might want to put it as a comment so that others can use it too.

Comment: https://github.com/tokilabs/getstream-react-native-typescript-example The author implements a user feed and notification feed. It's a good starting/reference point especially if you're using the same tech stack.

Comment: Well thank you  but we thank the Author more.